# Store the result of seq command into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shuffle

I need to store the output of this command into an array and print the array?

```
seq 0 9 | shuf
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
array=($(seq 0 9 | shuf))
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="3" [1]="6" [2]="2" [3]="8" [4]="0" [5]="9" [6]="5" [7]="7" [8]="4" [9]="1")'
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the output of your command into a array named `arr`:

```
arr=($(seq 0 9 | shuf))
```

Print the array by referencing it's variable name `arr`:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

**Example Output:**

```
4
0
5
1
2
7
6
8
3
9
```